# My sqlite3 request not return all the list

Tags: python, sqlite, request

my problem is that my sqlite3 request does not return the entire list, but part of it.

```
import sqlite3
miConexion = sqlite3.connect("MAGGIES")
miCursor = miConexion.cursor()
datos = miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM BEBIDAS")
```

Comment: How do you know?  This code does nothing with the resultset returned by the query.

Comment: Is `BEBIDAS` a table ?